Visual Studio Project Tab Not Loading After BSOD
I have the latest version of Visual Studio 2022. Today I opened the Publish Web App and clicked the publish button like I have done countless times but today I bot a BSOD right after clicking the button. Now every time I try to publish the website the publish tab will not load. It just has two tabs for "Connected Services" and "Publish" both of which display nothing. Normally you would be able to configure publishing options but instead I see a little blue loading spinner.
This is project specific. Whenever I try doing this with a different project nothing goes wrong. My guess is that something got messed up due to the BSOD.
I have tried repairing Visual Studio and deleting caches in the AppData folder but none of that worked. I looked at my publishing profile files in my solution and they load/look fine.
How do I get the publish tab to load in this project?
I expect to the publishing tab to load properly.

You probably have some corrupted file. I would try to add a new project to the solution, move all the files there and try to publish.

Have you deleted the hidden .vs folder for the solution?

This may be because some necessary files are damaged or missing due to BSOD. I suggest you reinstall VS to see if it works.
